# What a good alternative for Mendelson's math logic can I read?

Tags: lo.logic, books

I am a programmer and I am master of computer science. I remember we studied mathematical logic with Mendelson's book "Introduction to mathematical logic" and I barely understood this book because it was very hard to read (however I still remember something about computation theory). Recently, I tried to read Mendelson again but I found the book hard to read again because of plenty of symbols and signs and some statements are not evident for me :)

What would you recommend me to read before Mendelson?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for math.stackexchange, but FWIW I strongly recommend [Boolos/Burgess/Jeffrey](https://www.amazon.com/Computability-Logic-George-S-Boolos-ebook/dp/B00DO1HG40). Chapters $1$-$8$ can be largely skipped if you already know some formal model of computation (basically they're just playing with various models and proving some basic results), but starting with chapter $9$ we get a really nice treatment of basic proof and model theory leading up to a proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: I have a free book that I can email you, if you are interested.  (You can google my email.)  If it is still too hard to understand I might have some other suggestions.

Comment: @PaceNielsen is that an open offer?  Is there a url?  I liked Enderton's "Mathematical introduction to logic" but it's from a traditional perspective, probably not that good for computer science.

Comment: @none Yes, it is an open offer.  I wrote a (free) book that I'm currently testing in a classroom.  It has some sections on computation, that computer scientists might like.  Eventually I'll put a stable version on my website.